# How to test phonegap facebook oauth apps through Xcode or Android Emulator?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, cordova, facebook-oauth

How would I go about testing a phonegap native  app /facebook oauth app through Xcode (iPad / or iOs Simulator) or through Eclipse Android Simulator if facebook requires you to use a domain....in order for oauth to work..?

Answer (score 0):

You can install the native facebook app on your emulator. For example, you can found the facebook apk in the link below.

reference:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/

Comment: Okay, but that still doesn't resolve my issue. I am using the facebook oauth in my javascript. Which means I can't really login through my app to test the functions on my native device because I need to set a domain on facebooks end in which is the url of the site the apps hosted on (for the login to even appear). They're very secure about things. So how am I going to set it to a url through facebook to allow me to test the functions and login on my native device.

Comment: Facebook will look into the hash key. So if you are installing an app that is signed with a debug key in your emulator, you need to get the hash for that key and add it to your facebook app dashboard.

Comment: Ok thing is I'm not actually publishing these apps, I don't have a developer license so I'm not sure how to obtain a hash key? Do I need a developer license for iOS to be able to test facebook oauth on my ipad through xcode? I'm signing my ios apps with my schools cert to deploy my apps to my ipad for testing... and well android obv you can just test by plugging it in.

Comment: That's warrant another question. Hash key is only used for Android app. You can obtain the hash by this command keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64